# Codeigniter Ajax Dependent Dropdown doesn't work inside foreach statement

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, dependencies, dropdown

I made 2 dependent dropdown in the same page.
One of them is inside foreach statement and it doesn't work at all. Meanwhile the other one works well. The name of id are totally different. Both of dependent dropdown lists refer to the same function in controller. I thought its the main problem and tried to make a different function, but it didn't change anything.

VIEW :

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Category</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="edit_category" class="form-control" name="edit_category">
                  <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        <?php foreach ($categories as $cat) : ?>
                            <option <?php ?> value="<?php echo $cat->id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name 
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Product</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="edit_product" id="edit_product" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

SCRIPT :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //DEPENDENT DROPDOWN - ADD ITEM :
        $('#add_category').on('change', function() {
            $('#add_product').html('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
            var catID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/item/dependentDL') ?>",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    id_p_category: catID
                },
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#add_product').html(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }); //END - DROPDOWN - ADD ITEM


        //DEPENDENT DROPDOWN - EDIT ITEM :
        $('#edit_category').on('change', function() {
            $('#edit_product').html('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
            var edit_catID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/item/dependentDL') ?>",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    id_p_category: edit_catID
                },
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#edit_product').html(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In first dropdown there php tag is not closed. The right one should be <option value="<?php echo $cat->id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name ?> </option>

Comment: thanks to correct it but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should try with class instead of id because id is unique and your dropdown in the foreach loop so please try with class like below

```
  $('.add_category').on('change', function() {
        $('#add_product').html('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
        var catID = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/item/dependentDL') ?>",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id_p_category: catID
            },
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#add_product').html(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); //END - DROPDOWN - ADD ITEM


    //DEPENDENT DROPDOWN - EDIT ITEM :
    $('.edit_category').on('change', function() {
        $('#edit_product').html('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
        var edit_catID = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/item/dependentDL') ?>",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id_p_category: edit_catID
            },
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#edit_product').html(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. it works now, i didn't notice that i call the same object's name inside foreach. Finally i changed the <?php foreach ($categories as $c) : ?> and the other one is <?php foreach ($categories as $cat) : ?> They both were "$cat"